# how to make while loop start counting from 1

Tags: php, loops

I have a while loop which looks like this:

```
$condition2 = true;
$page = 1;

while($condition2){

    $page++;
    echo $page;



    if($page == 3){
        $condition2 = false;
    }
}
```

As you see i echo the page here. But it starts counting from 2 then goes to 3 etc. I want it to start counting from 1. so the output would be 1 -2 -3.

i tried making the default value outside the loop 0. This results in an endless loop.

Comment: Echo the variable *before* you increment it.

Comment: Change `$page = 1` to `$page = 0` ?

Comment: @rpm192 He said he tried that and it caused an infinite loop. But I'm not sure why that would happen.

Comment: @Barmar, Hmm.. Not sure why that would happen, curious though.

Comment: I have fleshed out my answer to include the entire modified code, plus a suggestion to tighten it up a little.

Comment: You could use `range` and `implode` and do it with 1 line. `echo implode(PHP_EOL, range(1,3));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the echo and increment together:

```
echo $page++;
```

You'll also have to change the exit condition:

```
$page > 3
```

So the entire code would be

```
$condition2 = true;
$page = 1;

while($condition2){

    echo $page++;

    if($page > 3){
        $condition2 = false;
    }

}
```

You can get rid of the `if` by assigning straight to $condition2:

```
$condition2 = true;
$page = 1;

while($condition2){

    echo $page++;
    $condition2 = ($page > 3);

}
```

And you could further shorten it up by making the loop dependent on $page, like this:

```
$page = 1;

while($page <= 3){

    echo $page++;

}
```

But if you want to use $page for something besides just echoing it in the loop, you'd have to modify this a little, so you're not modifying it while you're trying to use it:

```
$page = 0;

while($page++ < 3) { 

    echo $page; 
    //use $page for something

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing the page variable too soon. Add the page++ right at the end of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Either set `$page` to zero by changing:

```
$page = 1;
```

to:

```
$page = 0;
```

Or echo the variable before adding 1 to it:

```
$condition2 = true;
$page = 1;

while($condition2){

    echo $page;
    $page++



    if($page == 3){
        $condition2 = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you increment the counter at the end instead ?

```
$condition2 = true;
$page = 1;

while($condition2){

    echo $page;

    if($page == 3){
        $condition2 = false;
    }
    $page++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this

```
$condition2 = true;
$page = 1;
while($condition2){
    if($page == 3){
        $condition2 = false;
    }
    echo $page;
    $page++;
}
```